# VirtualBox failed to install in Fedora 26

Tags: fedora, software-installation, virtualbox

I encountered a problem following the Fedora 26 installation instructions on https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-with-yum-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

On the webpage's step 5, the `dnf install VirtualBox-5.2` command resulted in error messages, which I have given at the end of this forum query.  Since I didn't understand the significance of these messages, I continued with the step 5 `/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup` command.  This command failed; the `/usr/lib/virtualbox/` directory does **not** now exist.

**I know why the problem occurred but not how to remedy it.**  A few months ago, I installed `Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-26-1.5.iso`, and then manually executed `dnf install @cinnamon-desktop`, followed by `dnf install VirtualBox`.  At that time, I did not execute any other **VirtualBox Installation** related commands.  VirtualBox didn't show in the cinnamon launch menu and I subsequently forgot that I had installed it.  **I request help untangling this mess.**

```
***************************  start of messages  ********************************

[root@ip98-167-107-31 yum.repos.d]# dnf install VirtualBox-5.2
Last metadata expiration check: 0:17:20 ago on Fri 01 Dec 2017 01:09:48 AM PST.

dependencies resolved.

=================================================================================================================
 Package                    Arch               Version                              Repository              Size
=================================================================================================================
Installing:
 VirtualBox-5.2             x86_64             5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1              virtualbox              70 M

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 70 M
Installed size: 154 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64.rpm                                 15 MB/s |  70 MB     00:04    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Total                                                                             15 MB/s |  70 MB     00:04     
warning: /var/cache/dnf/virtualbox-4917f85f98c326df/packages/VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1     Signature,     key ID 98ab5139: NOKEY
Importing GPG key 0x98AB5139:
 Userid     : "Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>"
 Fingerprint: 7B0F AB3A 13B9 0743 5925 D9C9 5442 2A4B 98AB 5139
 From       : https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Key imported successfully
Running transaction check
    Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/VBox from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-server-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/VBoxTunctl from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-server-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/vbox-img from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-server-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/virtualbox.png from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-server-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/virtualbox.png from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-server-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/share/icons/hicolor/20x20/apps/virtualbox.png from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-server-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/virtualbox.png from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-server-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/share/icons/hicolor/40x40/apps/virtualbox.png from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-server-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/virtualbox.png from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-server-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/virtualbox.png from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-server-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mime/packages/virtualbox.xml from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-server-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64
  file /usr/share/pixmaps/VBox.png from install of VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.2_119230_fedora26-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package VirtualBox-5.1.30-2.fc26.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------

[root@ip98-167-107-31 yum.repos.d]#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `VirtualBox-5.2` package isn’t an upgrade for the existing packages you have installed, so you need to remove the latter:

```
sudo dnf remove VirtualBox VirtualBox-server
```

before installing `VirtualBox-5.2` again.

Comment: Stephen Kitt's answer apparently worked perfectly.  I was able to complete the install of VirtualBox 5.2.2 and then start it.

Answer (score 1):

Check downloading rpm package and install with rpm -Uvh --replacefiles

Comment: Thanks to Muhammed Sherief for his response.  I suspect that if I was more linux literate, I could have implemented it.