# Fedora 29 VirtualBox Installation Malfunction

Tags: fedora, software-installation, virtualbox

The only Fedora 29 specific instructions that I found are at this link:
https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Since that link is apparently focused on guest additions, I decided to ignore it.

A year ago, I successfully installed VirtualBox in Fedora 26 by following instructions that were similar to the following link: https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-with-yum-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Since I couldn't find corresponding instructions specifically for Fedora 29, I
attempted to follow the same instructions.  First, I executed the following 
command:

```
dnf install binutils gcc make patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel kernel-headers kernel-devel dkms
```

Although the command appeared to complete normally, it did show the following message:

```
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'virtualbox', ignoring this repo.
```

I then executed:

```
dnf install VirtualBox-5.2
```

Results:

```
Fedora 29 - x86_64 - VirtualBox                                               
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'virtualbox', ignoring this repo.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:45 ago on Sat 17 Nov 2018 03:40:42 PM PST.
No match for argument: VirtualBox-5.2
Error: Unable to find a match
```

I am not sure if this is relevant, but just out of curiosity, I executed

```
cd /
find -type f -iname "virtualbox.*"
find -type f -iname "virtualbox*"
```

Results:

```
./var/cache/PackageKit/29/metadata/updates-29-x86_64/packages/virtualbox-guest-additions-5.2.20-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm
./var/cache/PackageKit/29/metadata/updates-29-x86_64/packages/virtualbox-guest-additions-5.2.22-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm
```

It seems as if Fedora 29 (complete install, not upgrade) is installing *some*
VirtualBox Guest-Addition rpm's.  I will post a separate query re what I should do to install guest additions once I've got VirtualBox installed.  I mention it in this posting only as it might relate to my specific problem.

Similarly, I'm unsure whether the following link is relevant:
[VirtualBox failed to install in Fedora 26](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408173/virtualbox-failed-to-install-in-fedora-26)

In that link, I made a mistake and got UnixSE responses about backing out my
mistake before I did the install.

**Questions:**

1. Why am I getting the message "Failed to synchronize cache for repo virtualbox"?
2. Why am I getting the message "No match for argument: VirtualBox-5.2"?
3. Do I need to back anything out before I proceed with the install?
4. How do I install VirtualBox in Fedora 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the raw repo at http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/fedora/ they don't seem to support 29 yet, only up to F28. You should be able to edit the repo file and change `$releasever` to `28` and then `dnf install VirtualBox-5.2` .

Comment: @AaronDMarasco Aaron, thanks for the analysis.  Your approached worked but revealed an underlying problem.  When I re-attempted `dnf install VirtualBox-5.2`, I got several error messages similar to  Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libvpx.so.4()(64bit) needed by VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.0_118431_fedora26-1.x86_64.  I will wait a couple of months and then re-try.  It looks like your analysis answered my question 2.  I also welcome an answer for question 1.

Comment: Question 1 is because http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/fedora/29 is not a valid URL; it doesn't exist on the repo site. http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/fedora/28 is where I indicated you should point to. Some sources for your missing library can be found at https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libvpx.so.4()(64bit)

Comment: @AaronDMarasco Aaron, thanks again.  **For others:**  Following Aaron's original answer, my re-try did in fact point to ../rpm/fedora/28, which is why the re-try got different errors.  I suspect that it will be cleaner simply to wait a few months and then re-try.